# Python - how can i catch error of chown. chown: invalid user

Tags: python

If there is an error, I want to show this error to the messagebox and stop the if statement.

how can I catch the error guys?

Comment: you'll need to show some code. are you using shell commands in your code? are you using the subprocess module?

Comment: Sorry for missing coding. 

def execute(): 
    filez = tb_filepath.get() 
    O = tb_o.get() 
    G = tb_group.get() 
    chown = "chown " + O + ":" + G + " " + filez 
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
if i typed abc in O textbox, which is didn't have this user,
how can i out the invalid user error to the message box?

Comment: the correct place for that code is to edit it into your question. I don't know what modules you are using either. you also need to refer to the documentation. see Thavendren's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your calling it. If your using the subprocess module :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['chown', 'bad_user', '/file_path'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(err)
```

should give you:

> chown: bad_user: illegal user name

Now this is in Python 2.7. Python 3 has an easier way of calling it. Should be: (Not tested)

```
result = subprocess.run(['chown', 'bad_user', '/file_path'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result.stdout
```

Comment: im using os.popen() to run the command chown.
is there is any method to catch the error ?

Comment: Not sure about os.popen(), but you can get it using os.popen3:

import os

(child_stdin, child_stdout, child_stderr) = os.popen3('chown bad_user /Users/sravindran/test.py')
print('error = {}'.format(child_stderr.read()))

Also, all os.popen* functions have been deprecated since 2.6. You should technically be using the subprocess module. Just an FYI